Does Josephus have anything to say about the Jewish high priest Josef Ben Caiaphas. after the crucifixion of Jesus Christ?
Josef Ben Caiaphas was the Jewish high priest during the time of Jesus’ ministry and for a few years afterwards. He was a strong opponent of Jesus and His message.
Acts 4:1-22 informs us that Caiaphas continued to persecute the followers of Christ, being present at the trial of Peter and John.
He is believed to have been born around 14 B.C. and died a few years after the crucifixion of Jesus.  One source says he died in Crete and was buried in HaShalom Forest (Yaldei Israel Garden), Jerusalem.
I would like to know if Josephus has any additional information about Caiaphas after the crucifixion of Jesus and up to the death of Caiaphas.

Josephus records his removal from the office of high priest in Antiquities of the Jews, Book 18, Chapter 4. You can read the chapter in full here, the tl;dr is that the Samaritans rioted, Pilate killed a bunch of them, they complained to Vitellius, who at the time was running the show in Syria. He recalled Pilate to Rome, came to Jerusalem himself, and, among other activities, replaced Caiaphas with Jonathan the son of Ananus (better known as Annas to readers of the KJV). This happened about 36 AD.
As far as I can find, Josephus records nothing more about Caiaphas after that point and nothing about his death.

Yes, chapter 4 in Book 18 was too long/didn't read all of it, but enough to get the gist, which you summed up in a concise manner. Thanks for a refreshing approach and for getting to the point.

It is Josephus who informs us that Caiaphas' Hebrew name was Joseph. He also shows that Caiaphas' father-in-law Annas/Annanus was the head of a major priestly dynasty. This explains why Annas is portrayed in John's Gospel account as a kind of co-high priest senior to Annas (John 18:13) despite no longer being in office.  Besides what user111403 tells us of Caiaphas being removed after the demise of Pilate, Josephus gives information on all the known high priests who succeeded Caiaphas, most of whom were his relatives (brothers-in-law, nephews etc,). One of Annas' sons, Eleazar, was high priest shortly before Caiaphas took office.  The Jewish Encyclopedia contains a list of all the known high priests. This goes beyond what the OP asks, but I think it will be of interest. From the time of Herod onward its main source is Josephus' Antiquities:

Joseph (called "Caiaphas" (xviii. 2, § 2; 4, § 3; Matt. xxvi. 3, 57)
(Under Vitellius.)
Jonathan, son of Ananus/Annas (xviii. 4, § 3; "B. J." ii. 12, §§ 5-6; 13, § 3)
Theophilus, son of Ananus (xviii. 5, § 3)
(Under Agrippa.)
Simon, or Cantheras, son of Bœthus (xix. 6, § 2; see Grätz., "Gesch." 4th ed., iii. 739-746)
Mattathias, son of Ananus (xix. 6, § 4)
Elioneus, son of Cantheras (xix. 8, § 1; Parah iii. 5)
(Under Herod of Chalcis.)
Joseph, son of Cainus (xx. 1, § 3)
[Perhaps Ishmael (iii. 15, § 13) should be placed here.]
Ananias, son of Nebedeus (xx. 5, § 2; Derenbourg, "Hist." p. 233)
(Jonathan restored; xx. 8, § 5)
(Under Agrippa II.)
Ishmael, son of Fabi (xx. 8, §§ 8, 11; Parah iii. 5; Sotah ix. 5; Derenbourg, "Hist." pp. 232-235)
Joseph Cabi, son of Simon (xx. 8, § 11)
Ananus, son of Ananus (xx. 9, § 1)

Interestingly Theophilus, son of Ananus - therefore Caiaphas' brother-in-law - is thought by some scholars to be the Theophilus to whom Luke dedicated his gospel and the Book of Acts. This Theophilus was known to be a supporter of the peace party (according to Josephus) in the runup to the Revolt of 66-70 c.e. He was no longer high priest by that time, but his younger brother or nephew may have been. Theophilus could have held significant influence, similar to that of Annas with Caiaphas. The hypothesis is that he was a potential protector of the Christians of Jerusalem, who - like him - opposed the rebellion against Rome.
Summary: Josephus lets us know how Caiaphas' reign ended, and writes of several succeeding high priests who were his younger relatives, including one with the intriguing name Theophilus.

My interest is in Jesus Christ from Birth to his death then resurrection  8 B.C. to AD 42 Jesus was Judged by Political motivated evangelical types ! At that time  Jews namely Josef Ben Caiaphas died AD 46  plus Annas , It is sad to see Religion being abused even today in Politics over truth . Like John Jesus christs disciple we hear Gods point of view in Revelation concerning the seven churches , God will spew out the foul religious Men and Women of end times who seek power gold and Glory over the truth of Jesus Christ ..Jesus is the resurrection and Life John 11 ...........I also a fellow witness of Jesus Christ resurrected

Can you translate that to english?

I would like to know if Josephus has any additional information about Caiaphas after the crucifixion of Jesus and up to the death of Caiaphas. I'm looking for verifiable sources of information, not personal opinions. Please take our Tour (scroll down to the bottom left hand side of this screen) to see what we look for in answers.
